# get the div val() where the input was changed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML

```
<div>my content of the div1
  <input/>
</div>​

<div>my content of the div2
  <input/>
</div>​

<div>my content of the div3
  <input/>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  var x = $('this').parent('div').val();
    alert(x);
})​​​;
```

My problem is why cannot I get the content of the div which the input was changed ?

Comment: `val()` is for form fields. Are you looking for `html()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected Script**

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  var x = $(this).parent('div').html();
  alert(x);
})​​​;
```

- `val()` is for form fields only
- `this` should not be quoted.

**Alternative**

If you only want the text of the parent, you can use `text()`. However, browsers can differ on how they implement it (see the [notes here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)). In this case, it's probably cleaner to wrap the content you want in another element, like:

```
<div>
  <span>my content of the div1</span>
  <input/>
</div>​
```

And use script like:

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  var x = $('this').siblings("span").html();
  alert(x);
})​​​;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass the value of `this`, not a string "this", to jQuery, and call [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text content of an element, not `.val()` (which gets the value of an input element):

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
    var x = $(this).parent('div').text(); //`text` method gets contents of div
    //        ^ no quotes around `this`
    alert(x);
})​​​;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ge the contents of the div with `.html()`, not with `.val()` method. The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.
See [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery `val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only works on inputs not on generic html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('this')` to `$(this)`. (remove the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

.val() doesn't exist for others tags than select/input/textarea tags.
I'll suggest that you use .text() function or .html(), depending on what you would like to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
  var x = $(this).parent('div').text();
// OR var x = $(this).parent('div').html();
    alert(x);
})​​​;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$('input').bind('keyup',function(){ 
alert($(this).parent().html());
})
```